# find string in other column but same row vba

Tags: excel, vba

some cells in column D contains same numbers "123".
The macro needs to find the row of the string "xxx" in different column but same row that contains numbers "123".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good `INDEX(MATCH)` use case.

If your table is something like

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | xxx | 111 |
| B | yyy | 222 |
| C | zzz | 333 |

You can try something like

`=INDEX(A2:C4,MATCH(B2,B2:B4,0),3)`

Which will return `111` as you matched the row containing `xxx` and wanted column `3`